# Load balancer create failed in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a CloudFormation stack with implement Load Balancer from CDK java project. From CloudFormation service created YAML template. I am getting an error all the nine Loadbalancers:

> Not enough IP space available in subnet-dca571a5. ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet. (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet; Request ID: d50000d6-4e00-4004-a450-c000b4dd4f00; Proxy: null)

[image: CloudFormation Stack Status Reason]

Comment: Whats the configuration of the VPC you're trying to deploy this in? Have you checked the range and whether or not you indeed have the necessary number of IPs?

Comment: I'm checked with VPC ip range is 10.122.0.0/20

Comment: So what is the range of the subnets? Those ranges are different from the VPC range (but always a subnet if the range, as the name suggests :) )

Comment: What is your template creating the vpc and subnets?

Comment: **Side-question:** Why are you creating 9 Load Balancers? That is quite unusual.

Comment: Because already created with 9 servers. so have implemented 9 loadbalancers

Comment: Do each of those servers provide different traffic? If all of the servers are running the same app, then you would just need **one load balancer** in front of all the servers. Also, if you only have one server behind a load balancer, then you don't actually need a load balancer at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that CloudFormation failed to create the Load Balancer(s).

This was because each Load Balancer requires at least 8 free IP addresses in the subnet, and your subnet does not have that many available.

Your VPC is `10.122.0.0/20`, which gives a total of **4096 possible IP addresses**. However, this address space is then **divided amongst the subnets**. Of the space allocated to each subnet, some IP addresses would already be taken by your existing resources, and some IP addresses in each subnet are reserved.

**Bottom line:** Your subnets need to have a larger address space.

Comment: Also VPC accessing multiple subnet associate with servers. Then using loadbalancer1 to 9 cidrip:10.0.0.0/8                                                                                                                      
                         {
   "type": "inbound",
   "cidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8",
   "ipProtocol": "tcp",
   "fromPort": 22101,
   "toPort": 22101,
   "loadBalancer": "LoadBalancer1"
  },

Comment: You can add additional CIDR ranges to a VPC, but you cannot change the CIDR of a subnet.